C# plugin for AutoCAD has interface members that "aren't implemented" but still builds?
I am trying to make it so I can add properties to the Object Property Manager (OPM) in AutoCAD. I'm following these articles Part 1 Part2
I also forked this project from Github, which follows these articles.
After getting things set up to work for AutoCAD 2024 and ObjectARX 2024, the C++ (which I'm very unfamiliar with) compiles and builds.
The C# portion also builds. But there are errors that would make be believe it shouldn't


[
    Guid("F60AE3DA-0373-4d24-82D2-B2646517ABCB"),
    ProgId("OPMNetSample.CustomProperty.1"),

    // No class interface is generated for this class and
    // no interface is marked as the default.
    // Users are expected to expose functionality through
    // interfaces that will be explicitly exposed by the object
    // This means the object can only expose interfaces we define

    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
    // Set the default COM interface that will be used for
    // Automation. Languages like: C#, C++ and VB allow to 
    //query for interface's we're interested in but Automation 
    // only aware languages like javascript do not allow to 
    // query interface(s) and create only the default one

    ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IDynamicProperty2)),
    ComVisible(true)
]
public class CustomProp : IDynamicProperty2 {
    private IDynamicPropertyNotify2 m_pSink =null;

   // Unique property ID
    void IDynamicProperty2.GetGUID(out Guid propGUID)
    {
        propGUID = new Guid("F60AE3DA-0373-4d24-82D2-B2646517ABCB");
    }

    // Property display nameD
    void IDynamicProperty2.GetDisplayName(out string szName)
    {
        szName = "My integer property";
    }

    // Show/Hide property in the OPM, for this object instance
    void IDynamicProperty2.IsPropertyEnabled(object pUnk, out int bEnabled)
    {
        bEnabled = 1;
    }

    // Is property showing but disabled
    void IDynamicProperty2.IsPropertyReadOnly(out int bReadonly)
    {
        bReadonly = 0;
    }

    // Get the property description string
    void IDynamicProperty2.GetDescription(out string szName)
    {
        szName = "This property is an integer";
    }

    // OPM will typically display these in an edit field
    // optional: meta data representing property type name,
    // ex. ACAD_ANGLE
    void IDynamicProperty2.GetCurrentValueName(out string szName)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    // What is the property type, ex. VT_R8
    void IDynamicProperty2.GetCurrentValueType(out ushort varType)
    {
        // The Property Inspector supports the following data
        // types for dynamic properties:
        // VT_I2, VT_I4, VT_R4, VT_R8,VT_BSTR, VT_BOOL
        // and VT_USERDEFINED. 

        varType = 3; // VT_I4
    }

    // Get the property value, passes the specific object
    // we need the property value for.
    void IDynamicProperty2.GetCurrentValueData(object pUnk, ref object pVarData)
    {
        // TODO: Get the value and return it to AutoCAD

        // Because we said the value type was a 32b int (VT_I4)
        pVarData = (int)4;
    }

    // Set the property value, passes the specific object we
    // want to set the property value for
    void IDynamicProperty2.SetCurrentValueData(object pUnk, object varData)
    {
        // TODO: Save the value returned to you

        // Because we said the value type was a 32b int (VT_I4)
        int myVal = (int)varData;
    }

    // OPM passes its implementation of IDynamicPropertyNotify, you
    // cache it and call it to inform OPM your property has changed
    void IDynamicProperty2.Connect(object pSink)
    {
        m_pSink = (IDynamicPropertyNotify2)pSink;
    }

    void IDynamicProperty2.Disconnect()
    {
        m_pSink = null;
    }

}

IDynamicProperty2 comes from the C++ project which is responsible for making this available to .NET
//- IDynamicProperty2.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace Autodesk::AutoCAD::Runtime;
using namespace Autodesk::AutoCAD::DatabaseServices;

#include "dynprops.h"

namespace Autodesk
{
  namespace AutoCAD
  {
    namespace Windows
    {
      namespace OPM
      {
        [InteropServices::Guid("9CAF41C2-CA86-4ffb-B05A-AC43C424D076")]
        [InteropServices::InterfaceTypeAttribute(InteropServices::ComInterfaceType::InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        [InteropServices::ComVisible(true)]
        public interface class IDynamicProperty2
        {
          void GetGUID(
            [InteropServices::Out] System::Guid% propGUID
          );
          void GetDisplayName(
            [InteropServices::Out,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
              InteropServices::UnmanagedType::BStr
             )
            ] interior_ptr<System::String^> name);
          void IsPropertyEnabled(
            [InteropServices::In,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::IUnknown
             )
            ] Object^ pUnk,
            [InteropServices::Out] System::Int32% bEnabled
          );
          void IsPropertyReadOnly(
            [InteropServices::Out] System::Int32% bReadonly
          );
          void GetDescription(
            [InteropServices::Out,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::BStr
             )
            ] interior_ptr<System::String^> description
          );
          void GetCurrentValueName(
            [InteropServices::Out,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::BStr
             )
            ] interior_ptr<System::String^> name
          );
          void GetCurrentValueType(
            [InteropServices::Out] ushort% pVarType
          );
          void GetCurrentValueData(
            [InteropServices::In,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::IUnknown
             )
            ] Object^ pUnk,
            [InteropServices::In,
             InteropServices::Out,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::Struct
             )
            ] interior_ptr<Object^> varData
          );
          void SetCurrentValueData(
            [InteropServices::In,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::IUnknown
             )
            ] Object^ pUnk,
            [InteropServices::In,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::Struct
             )
            ] Object^ varData
          );
          void Connect(
            [InteropServices::In,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               /*IDynamicPropertyNotify2*/
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::IUnknown
             )
            ] Object^ pSink
          );
          void Disconnect();
        };
        [InteropServices::Guid(
           "975112B5-5403-4197-AFB8-90C6CA73B9E1"
        )]
        [InteropServices::InterfaceTypeAttribute(
           InteropServices::ComInterfaceType::InterfaceIsIUnknown
        )]
        [InteropServices::ComVisible(true)]
        public interface class IDynamicPropertyNotify2
        {
          void OnChanged(
            [InteropServices::In,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::IUnknown
             )
            ] Object^ pDynamicProperty
          );
          void GetCurrentSelectionSet(
            [InteropServices::In,
             InteropServices::Out,
             InteropServices::MarshalAs(
               InteropServices::UnmanagedType::Struct
             )
            ] interior_ptr<Object^> pSelection
          );
        };
      }
    }
  }
}

And this is the declaration for IDynamicProperty2 that is part of the ObjectARX API which is in dynprops.h
//--------------------------
// IDynamicProperty2 interface
// Implement this class to create dynamic properties for the PropertyPalette
// it defines the base set of property attributes as well as
// the name/type/data tuples. 
//--------------------------
// {9CAF41C2-CA86-4ffb-B05A-AC43C424D076}
DEFINE_GUID(IID_IDynamicProperty2, 0x9caf41c2, 0xca86, 0x4ffb, 0xb0, 0x5a, 0xac, 0x43, 0xc4, 0x24, 0xd0, 0x76);

interface DECLSPEC_UUID("9CAF41C2-CA86-4ffb-B05A-AC43C424D076")
IDynamicProperty2 : public IUnknown
{
    BEGIN_INTERFACE
    // *** IUnknown methods ****

    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(THIS_ REFIID riid, LPVOID FAR* ppvObj) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)(THIS) PURE;

    // *** IDynamicProperty2 methods ***
    //Unique property ID
    STDMETHOD(GetGUID)(THIS_ /*[out]*/GUID* propGUID) PURE;
    // Property display name
    STDMETHOD(GetDisplayName)(THIS_ /*[out]*/BSTR* bstrName) PURE;
    // Show/Hide property in the OPM, for this object instance 
    STDMETHOD(IsPropertyEnabled)(THIS_ /*[in]*/IUnknown *pUnk,
                                      /*[out]*/BOOL* pbEnabled) PURE;
    // Is property showing but disabled
    STDMETHOD(IsPropertyReadOnly)(THIS_ /*[out]*/BOOL* pbReadonly) PURE;
    // Get the property description string
    STDMETHOD(GetDescription)(THIS_ /*[out]*/BSTR* bstrName) PURE;
    
    // *** Basic property value information ***
    // OPM will typically display these in an edit field
    
    // optional: meta data representing property type name, ex. ACAD_ANGLE
    STDMETHOD(GetCurrentValueName)(THIS_ /*[out]*/BSTR* pbstrName) PURE;
    // What is the property type, ex. VT_R8
    STDMETHOD(GetCurrentValueType)(THIS_ /*[out]*/VARTYPE* pVarType) PURE;
    // Get the property value, passes the specific object we need the property
    // value for.
    STDMETHOD(GetCurrentValueData)(THIS_ /*in*/IUnknown *pUnk, 
                                      /*[out]*/VARIANT* pvarData) PURE;
    // Set the property value, passes the specific object we want to set the 
    // property value for
    STDMETHOD(SetCurrentValueData)(THIS_ /*[in]*/IUnknown *pUnk, 
                                         /*[in]*/const VARIANT varData) PURE;

    //*** Notifications ***
    //OPM passes its implementation of IDynamicPropertyNotify, you
    //cache it and call it to inform OPM your property has changed
    STDMETHOD(Connect)(THIS_ /*[in]*/IDynamicPropertyNotify2* pSink) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Disconnect)(THIS_ ) PURE;
};

typedef IDynamicProperty2 FAR* LPDYNAMICPROPERTY2;

If I try to "fix" the errors as suggested in Visual Studio, this happens when I go to build
this is the changed code
// Property display nameD
void IDynamicProperty2.GetDisplayName(ref string szName)
{
    szName = "My integer property";
}
// Get the property description string
void IDynamicProperty2.GetDescription(ref string szName)
{
    szName = "This property is an integer";
}

// OPM will typically display these in an edit field
// optional: meta data representing property type name,
// ex. ACAD_ANGLE
void IDynamicProperty2.GetCurrentValueName(ref string szName)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}

And when I go to build I get these errors


Looks to me like you're dealing with an ancient design mistake in ObjectARX.  Automation demands that objects passed by reference are annotated with either [in, out] or [out, retval].  Just plain [out] is not correct.  That never mattered much in the olden days, languages like C++ and Basic don't care.  But C# does.  Way too late to fix that.  Just make sure that you avoid the possible memory leak, always call GetDisplayName() et al with the string argument variable initialized to null.

So there is no way to modify the wrapper to fix this?

I changed these declarations in the IDynamicProperty2.h file of the c++ project
void GetDisplayName(
  [InteropServices::In,//added
   InteropServices::Out,
   InteropServices::MarshalAs(
    InteropServices::UnmanagedType::BStr
   )
  ] interior_ptr<System::String^> name);

void GetDescription(
  [InteropServices::In,//added
   InteropServices::Out,
   InteropServices::MarshalAs(
     InteropServices::UnmanagedType::BStr
   )
  ] interior_ptr<System::String^> description
);
void GetCurrentValueName(
  [InteropServices::In,//added
   InteropServices::Out,
   InteropServices::MarshalAs(
     InteropServices::UnmanagedType::BStr
   )
  ] interior_ptr<System::String^> name
);

Then changed the C# code to use ref
void IDynamicProperty2.GetDisplayName(ref string szName)
{
    szName = "My integer property";
}

void IDynamicProperty2.GetDescription(ref string szName)
{
    szName = "This property is an integer";
}

void IDynamicProperty2.GetCurrentValueName(ref string szName)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}

I built these changes in both projects and then not loaded the example project and it worked great!
